# Creating a login portal via NanoHTTPD. Help maintaining session

Tags: java, nanohttpd

I am creating a simple Java website and using NanoHTTPD to allow easy control between the web server and the game server.

I would like to create a login portal so clients are able to view their game server status and manage this.

I have run into a brick wall because I do not know how to use a session/access token. I do not know how in PHP either.

I have thought about using an IP session, but then people in public wifi hotspots might have their server managed by someone else. I've thought about a Cookie, but this could easily be edited to give access to other people's server.

So my question is how can I store a value by the browser for the access token without having to put a form for everything they click, and how can I keep them logged in (preferrably without storing a password in a cookie)

Answer (score 1):

The answer I've seen used is an encrypted cookie. Google around, it is either in NanoHTTPD  or you can implement something with Jasypt (simple Java encryption lib)

Comment: If you want security, no, because they will be able to find the session from the name of the game server (although it won't be as obvious). It should be something only the server can generate, such as hash("game server name"+salt) or more secure encrypt_with_server_key("name_of_game_server"+timestamp). You don't need the password stored with the user session. Actually you shouldn't store the password on server but only a hash of it for checking the right one was entered. Have a look at Jasypt docs, http://www.jasypt.org/easy-usage.html, they made encryption quite easy.

Comment: Ok thank you. I will put Username + 1st 5 letters of the password hash. Would take lots of bruteforcing.

Comment: Btw, while I'm pushing tools I like. The Play Framework will do some of the heavy lifting including setting encrypted key=value pairs in the client. If you use Jasypt, the first letters of the password digest is actually the salt (chars added to the password so brute force cracking can't use a pre-made dictionary).